# Create new column in query using doctrine2

Tags: symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I'm working on symfony2 project using doctrine2, I have an issue about creating a new button for user connected to a form to add 10 new fields with 10 values of course and 10 columns in DB:

*that means when a user click "add new" button so he can adding one field X with XV value and creating one colomun "X" too in database , then second field Y with YV... until 10.Also XV AND YV are the same type of field for example "decimal".*

I don't have problem with adding a new field in form using ajax,but my questions are :

1- How to create a new column in a table in DB with doctrine2 and insert value too?

2- how to update Class Entity and Class form too automatically in the same time when a new column is created?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to admit I did not understand the goal you are trying to achieve completely. But I am almost positive, that there is a conceptual mistake in your design.

You have to distinguish between the following two concepts:

- **DML** (Data Manipulation Language), such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE data in/from the database, meaning that you create new records (INSERT).
- **DDL** (Data Definition Language), such as CREATE TABLE (to create a new database relation) or ALTER TABLE (to add new columns to the database).

You are trying to use **DDL** (ALTER TABLE statements according to your description) to dynamically add new columns to your database, which is not effective and not good practice at all. **You should have an extremely good reason to do it that way** (e.g. if the system you are building is a database administration tool or something like this...).

I would heavily recommend you to **completely rethink and redesign your architecture and use DML** to achive your goal. I am sure your problem can be solved by designing a flexible data structure and not adding new columns, but inserting new records in a dynamic database.

After you have redesigned your database structure it will be very easy to implement your task with Symfony and Doctrine.